# How to insert data from Excel into a database

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I'm looking for a solution to import data from an Excel file into a database (for example: MS Access file).

I can get the idea as well as the structure but because I'm new to something like this it is really hard to finish the work.

Below is my code, which should do these:

1. Select database
2. Select import files
3. Create connection using ADODB
4. I'm stuck here, using `Insert` statement to import but how? Because the values to import would be a value of a variable run from the very first cell of Excel files till the end of it.

Please ignore the comment because I'm using my native language to easier understand in future

```
Sub Import_Data()
'Khai bao bien lien quan den Database
Dim connection As ADODB.connection
Dim record As ADODB.Recordset
'Khai bao cau lenh Query
Dim SQLstr As String
'Khai bao connection string
Dim connectionstring As String
Dim dbstring As String
'Duong dan den file import
Dim fdlg As FileDialog


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Chon datafile
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Access files", "*.accdb, *.mdb"
If .Show = True Then
datapath = .SelectedItems(1)
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End With


'Chon file import
Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fdlg
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls,*.xlsx,*.xlsm"
If .Show = True Then
importstring = .SelectedItems(1)
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End With

'Connect to Database
Set connection = New ADODB.connection
With connection
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.connectionstring = "Data Source=" & datapath & ";"
.ConnectionTimeout = 30
.Open
If .State = adStateOpen Then
MsgBox "welcome " & Environ("Username") & " ket noi den database"
Else: Exit Sub
End If
End With

Dim a, c As Integer
Dim b, d As Integer
Dim ImpWb As Workbook
Dim ImpWs As Worksheet

Set ImpWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(importstring)
ImpWb.Application.Visible = True
Set ImpWs = ImpWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ImpWs.UsedRange
a = .Rows.Count
b = .Columns.Count
For c = 2 To a
For d = 1 To b
SQLstr = "Insert into Test values(" & Cells(c, d).Value & ")"
connection.Execute SQLstr
Next d
Next c
End With
ImpWb.Close
connection.Close
Set ImpWs = Nothing
Set ImpWb = Nothing
Set connection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? And what is the exact question. (see [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above it's become clearer now that the issue you face is *how to build the SQL statements inside VBA*. However, you are very much closer than you think.

This function below will build an insert statement for each row of data **provided the columns in the Excel tab is exactly equal to and in exact order as the fields in the SQL table**. It also will combine all the inserts into one statement so you can execute all the rows at once.

```
With ImpWs.UsedRange

    a = .Rows.Count
    b = .Columns.Count

    For c = 2 To a

        SQLstr = SQLstr & "INSERT INTO TEST VALUES("

        For d = 1 To b

            SQLstr = SQLStr & .Cells(c, d).Value & iif(d <> b, ",","")

        Next d

        SQLstr = SQLStr & ");"

    Next c

End With
```

The other caveat is that assumes all fields are numerical. If you have some text fields you will have to add `'` before and after each field, like `' & .Cells(c, d).Value & & '`. If you know the columns that need text, you can modify the input with a Select Case on column number as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you recognize or discovered already the magic connection.execute function. Here is the music playing. All its need is a valid SQL string to insert. That's (nearly) all.
SQL Strings can be fired single by single or a bunch separated by a ";" at the end

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2 ,..)
    VALUES 
        (value1,value2 ,...),
        (value1,value2 ,...),
        ...
         (value1,value2 ,...); --<<<<<<<<<<< see the ";"
```

In your case you has to define the affected columns in the first line and then just all the values for a line inside the braces. If this do not work - something is wrong with the SQL string. You can use access which has a nice SQL builder to create a sql template or maybe use a online sql tester to see if your sql is valid. For testing purposes i suggest to just add one line first. And another hint: The values has to be escaped ! So add first something trivial like "abc" or 1234 just to check out the principle function. Life datas might have things like this >"< inside or "," or other things which could be seen as sql statement. Which will end up like it will do nothing at all. So read the manual how access escaped such poisoned text fragments ;)  And implement a function to avoid that. SQLITE has a nice tutorial and example page. SQLITE is nearly like access. To get a overview i would read there first and the M$ documentation a biut later. Have fun :)

Comment: Thanks Thomas

This like learning write sentences and day by day i know i ill improve my skill thanks to your comment.

Btw, My data is big, it should be thousand lines per day and would be huge for month which I can't type exact value inside the parentheses. That's what I'm fighting.

I know i just type something like

"For c = 1 to a
SQLstr = "Insert into table(Column1) Values(" & Cells(1,a).value & ")" "

then execute SQLstr to import data to one column of database.

But what if my database has morethan ten or twenty columns?

Comment: Thats why those lines are usually are autogenerated. There is also a sql function which will import the whole thing as csv file. I suggest to read a bit more about SQL first. THIS is the real power and not the access or excel thing you use. BTW SQL is much faster as ado ;). And it is also way more easy to create SQL strings instead of fiddeling ado things together. Except the escape issue. But that you can put in one clever routine and can forget about later.  Ive written some wrappers for my belongings to generate standard sql things.  Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also this approach using SQL

```
Sub test()

Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim s As String
Dim strSQL As String

s = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=c:\…...\TestDBs\API_TEST.accdb;" & _
        "Persist Security Info=False;"

Set c = New ADODB.Connection
c.ConnectionString = s
c.Open

 ' Excel workbook, sheet name test1

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblDestination ( Firstname )" & _
            "SELECT [test1$].FirstName " & _
            "FROM [EXCEL 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\Databases\csv\test1.xlsx].[test1$];"

c.Execute strSQL

c.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You are brilliant.

I got the idea of this.

But how about my database have twenty columns and my excel have the same columns?
Is there anyway set a variable to them?

Comment: `DATABASE=C:\Databases\csv\test1.xlsx].[test1$a5:a10];`